# Debugging with expressions in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have just starting learning how to code in C++ / Qt and cannot seem to figure out how to debug certain objects in my code.

Take the following example:

```
QDir searchDirectory(dirPath);

QFileInfoList files = searchDirectory.entryInfoList();

foreach(QFileInfo file, files)
{
    if(file.isDir())
    {
    }
    else if(file.isFile())
    {
        ui->lstResults->addItem(file.absoluteFilePath());
    }
}
```

If i place a breakpoint on the *"if(file.isDir())"* section, i cannot seem to retrieve much information from what *file* contains - all i get is *d_ptr* of type *QSharedDataPointer*.

Is there a way to view the actual members and properties of this object?

I took a screenshot in the hope that i would be understood better:

[image: Debugging]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/debug.html

http://wiki.qt.io/Dpointer

Try

```
#include <QDebug>

// ...

qDebug() << "Debug QFileInfo" << file.isDir() << file.absoluteFilePath();
```

Hope that helps.